# is view.setOnTouchListener(listener) multicast? how does it work?

Tags: android, view

My question is regarding the effects of calling setOnTouchListener multiple times with either the same or a different listener.

> view.setOnTouchListener(myListener);

I understand that this will end up calling the "public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)" method in the myListener class on Motion Events. What I don't understand is what happens when I later call this:

> view.setOnTouchListener(myOtherListener);

does the myListener still receive Motion Events?

Also, if I call

> view.setOnTouchListener(myListener);

again, does it call myListener.onTouch twice on every touch event? Finally, how do you unsubscribe as the listener?

I took a look through the [dev guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/ui-events.html) but didn't find anything explicitly calling out how this or similar setListeners worked, but if anyone has a bookmark handy or knows how this works off-hand it would be appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The general rule is when function starts with "set" it replaces previous listener. If you want to unregister listener use `view.setOnTouchListener(null);`.

```
 view.setOnTouchListener(myListener); 
 /* myListener is active */
 view.setOnTouchListener(myOtherListener); 
 /* myListener is inactive, myOtherListener is active */
 view.setOnTouchListener(myListener);
 /* myListener is active, myOtherListener is inactive */
```

If there is an additive logic, you'll usually see `add` or `register` prefix in function name. For example, [`TextView.addTestChangedListener()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#addTextChangedListener%28android.text.TextWatcher%29) and `Context.registerReceiver()`.